# How do I remove the space inside the html table cell above the Vertically rotated text

Tags: html, css

Kindly refer to the fiddle code: 
https://jsfiddle.net/prtheei/207kvqtm/

How do I remove the space between the "VerticalText" and the right margin on the table. All I want is a small column to the right of my table spanning 5 rows and containing vertically rotated text. But on rotating the text, a huge space is created between the text and the right margin.

[Table View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpFlx.png)

Code:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<style>
  table {
    width: 900px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
  }
  tr {
    border: 1px black solid;
  }
  td {
    border: 1px black solid;
    width: 28%;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 8px;
  }
  .tdInfo {
    vertical-align: middle;
     transform: rotate(90deg);
     -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); /* Safari/Chrome */
    -webkit-transform-origin: 20px;
     -moz-transform: rotate(90deg); /* Firefox */
     -moz-transform-origin: 20px;
     -o-transform: rotate(90deg); /* Opera */
    -o-transform-origin: 20px;
     -ms-transform: rotate(90deg); /* IE 9 */
    -ms-transform-origin: 20px;
    transform-origin
  }
  .tdTime {
    width: 10%;
    vertical-align: top;
    font-weight:bold;
  } 
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="tdTime">09:30</td>
    <td colspan="4"><center>Row1</center></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tdTime">10:30</td>
    <td colspan="3"><center>Row2</center></td>
    <td class="tdInfo" rowspan="5">VerticalText</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tdTime">11:30</td>
    <td>Row3Col2</td>
    <td>Row3Col3</td>
    <td>Row3Col4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tdTime">12:30</td>
    <td>Row4Col2</td>
    <td>Row4Col3</td>
    <td>Row4Col4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tdTime">13:30</td>
    <td>Row5Col2</td>
    <td>Row5Col3</td>
    <td>Row5Col4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tdTime">14:30</td>
    <td colspan="3"><center>Row 6</center></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's better if you wrap the text in a div and you rotate the inner div, not the  `<td>` tag. Rotate a TD is dangerous.

Comment: Get rid of your 90deg transforms for a second, the cell is taking the width of the text as a minimum width.

Comment: @rsn - I dint know that. Tnx. Seems I have to alter it with a div inside td like Johannes has answered. Then it does not affect the size of the column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution, but it changes your HTML a little bit. It puts the text of that cell in an seperate `div` (with class "extra") that's put *into* the `td`, gets position absolute plus horizontal and vertical centering. I also had to define a fixed width, otherwise the text would break into two lines. Apart from that I removed `transform-origin: 20px;` from `.tdInfo` to allow the centering as done below:

https://jsfiddle.net/L420gybb/

This is the changed HTML part:

This is the changed and added CSS:

```
 .tdInfo {
    vertical-align: middle;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); /* Safari/Chrome */
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg); /* Firefox */
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg); /* Opera */
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg); /* IE 9 */
  }
.extra {
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
   text-align: center;
   width: 120px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution. But the text seems to be flying out of the table when viewed in Internet Explorer. I am using version IE11. Is there a workaround or solution for this